# Class 'Twig_Function' not found

Tags: docker, twig, slim

i have problems on all my slim3/twig projects.
i have this error : `Class 'Twig_Function' not found.`

my project were working well 1 month ago.
see one example : https://github.com/felixleo22/Smash2 (sorry it's in french language)

if someone got this error and got the issue, I will be very happy
if more details are needed, i will be there to answer

Comment: Did you upgrade your project? If so u'd need to use `\Twig\TwigFunction` from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig 3 support has been added to [slimphp/Twig-View](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/pull/158) exactly one month ago in version [2.5.1](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/pull/158/files).

Twig 3 has dropped all deprecated functions like `Twig_Function`. You should use `\Twig\TwigFunction` instead.

Comment: it's works, thanks